# Экстренное завершение работы программы python

Tags: python, исключения

Если коротко, есть программы на python, которая работает с текстовым документом и если ее экстренно завершить, в следующий раз программа может неправильно с ним работать. В интернете я не нашел ничего, ни исключения не функции, при завершении программы python - она просто закрывается. Нужно, что бы после завершения программы документ сохранялся или что то вроде того.

Comment: Что такое "экстренное завершение"? Каков механизм работы "экстренного завершения" в вашей операционной системе? Может оказаться, что ваша ОС в принципе не позволит сохранить что-либо независимо от вашего желания. И вообще почему вы доводите ситуацию до "экстренного завершения"?

Comment: @andreymal `os.abort()` , `return sys.exit(1)` etc. ?

Comment: Экстренное завершение - закрытие консоли, не нажатие сочетания клавиш или завершение программы через команду, а просто закрытие консоли

Answer (score 1):

Плохо искали. Пример из [документации](https://docs.python.org/3/library/atexit.html) описывает ваш случай:

```
try:
    with open("counterfile") as infile:
        _count = int(infile.read())
except FileNotFoundError:
    _count = 0

def incrcounter(n):
    global _count
    _count = _count + n

def savecounter():
    with open("counterfile", "w") as outfile:
        outfile.write("%d" % _count)

import atexit
atexit.register(savecounter)
```

Comment: Если я правильно понимаю, atexit работает только в случае завершении работы программы самостоятельно, а не при экстренном завершении

Comment: В любом случае, кроме падения интерпретатора, например по segfault. Но на такие случае способов просто не существует.

Comment: Что ж, на то мы и программисты, делаем то, на что другие не способны

Comment: Если только написать свой интерпретатор Python. Хотя и в этом случае стопроцентной гарантии не будет.